# Cheap linear actuator recommendations?

Tags: motor, actuator, buying

I've been doing a lot of research into linear actuators, and have come up pretty much empty handed in finding any small sized (lifting force 10-30 newtons)  linear actuators for a doable price (30-50 dollars).  I've seen some diy rack and pinion designs, and while prototyping I ended up turning a servo into a linear actuator with a lift arm, but I'm not much of a machinist, and would much rather a all in one solution.

So does anyone know of anywhere that sells 30-50 dollar linear actuators? Or will I always need to make them myself?

Comment: This is a mechanical engineering question, without much of  electrical engineering aspect, which this site is about. Also, it is a request for a shopping recommendation, and those are frowned upon here, unfortunately. I'm sure some of us are tempted to answer it, nevertheless!

Comment: DIY can be easyish depending on required lifetime. Nut on a thread can give you a reasonable reduction ratio.Worm drive to gear gives you N:1 for an N tooth gear and a 1-start worm (which almost all will be).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DIY can be easyish depending on required lifetime.

(1) Nut on a thread can give you a reasonable reduction ratio.
If this is for one off or a few and depending on size then battery-drill motor plus gearboxes driving a threaded rod may work for you. [I'm lifting ~= 100 kg using these so your 30 N figures is easily met :-). Battery powered screw drivers can also be used. As a screwdriver is usually of lower gearing you could use a linear linkage from a "con rod" directly off a driven wheel of desired size to get the travel you need.

[An example](http://www.xrobots.co.uk/linearactuator.htm)

Ha ha / Wow [Pet feeder linear actuatoir using a RC servo](http://mad-science.wonderhowto.com/how-to/build-vacation-pet-feeder-with-diy-linear-actuator-0134695/)

Instructables [RC servo based - low speed linear feed](http://www.instructables.com/id/Hack-your-servo-V100-Turn-your-servo-into-a-pow/)- OK for ideqas.

(2) Worm drive to gear gives you N:1 for an N tooth gear and a 1-start worm (which almost all will be). Driven gear to "con rod" gives linear output.

Answer (score 5):

Search for "door lock actuator".  If you don't mind closing your own control loops externally (current/position), then automotive power door lock linear actuators are a great way to get a compact linear actuator at a low price (provided that you don't need much mechanical reduction)

[image]

Comment: Just ordered a few in to play with, thanks for the suggestion :)

Answer (score 2):

You don't give much in the way of specs beyond force, but I suggest peeking at [Firgelli Technologies](http://www.firgelli.com/products.php?id=41).  They're not quite in your price range, but not all that far off, and they can be ordered with a few different control interfaces.  It feels like a fair price.